# Matching <hx id="label">

Tags: xslt

I  have source like

```
  <h1> ...  <h1>
```

(h1 may be h2 and h3 too.)
h1 MAY have an id attribute.
If it does NOT have an "id" attribute, I want to give it one.
How would the template look, to match an h1 WITHOUT and attribute "id", and how would I process the tag then?
Maybe like this?:

```
   <xsl:template match="(h1 | h2 | h3)[not(@id)]" >
   <!-- here I have to generate a tag h1, h2 or h3: how? -->
   <xsl:attribute name="id">G10.2</xsl:attribute>
   </h123>
   </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="h1[not(@id)] | h2[not(@id)] | h3[not(@id)]" >
    <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:attribute name="id">G10.2</xsl:attribute>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```